# How was plagiarism checked before the Internet?

Tags: publications, plagiarism

In the days where many prominent researchers we know today started their journey in Academia, what was the likelihood that some of their publications were alternated versions of what was already published by other researchers from other countries beforehand? Since most research is already published on the internet, and the existence of advanced plagiarism checking tools, has there been a recheck of authenticity of difference in papers that were published pre-1980s?

This is likely a dumb question since I am still learning the ways of Academia so don't get offended.

Comment: Look out for principles that nowadays have hyphenated names: the Newton-Raphson method, the Runge-Kutta method, the Oberbeck-Boussinesq approximation, the Fermi-Dirac distribution, the Kutta-Zhukovskiy theorem, the Frank-Read source,...

Comment: @DanielHatton, how does that relate to plagiarism, which is not the same as parallel research.

Comment: @Buffy, True, but I'm speaking to the "alternated versions" wording in the body of the question, not to the "plagiarism" wording in the title.

Comment: Tom Lehrer had a bit to say about this... But how do you plagiarize with no access to somebody else’s work? Parallel development is a totally different thing.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  There has never been a systematic method of plagiarism checking that actually worked.

Comment: There is not a real activity as a priori plagiarism checking. There is not a real activity for fraud checking. Given the right time, science adjust itself. Of course trouble of all sort can arise from misconduct, but this is just at our miserable scale. What is true that a simple software can now do things that weren't possible before. Like asking on this site.